# Fill Method Question in C++ for a Class 'AList'?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am new to programming and was wondering if someone may guide me in the following problem? Thank you, any advice will be helpful.

1. Implement a fill method in AList class to fill all the elements in the list with a given value it. For example, let L=[1, 2, 3] . A call to L.fill(0) will make L=[0, 0, 0].
   Below is a skeleton of the AList class:

```cpp
template <typename ItemType> class AList (
private: 
    /**The underlying array. */ 
    ItemType *items;

    /**Stores the current size of the list. */ 
    int count;

    /** max number of items allowed. */
    int maxCnt;

public: 

    // Other functions omitted.

    void fill(const ItemType &it);
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: the for loop? I'm having trouble understanding where to put maxCnt into place

Comment: Since you're only filling active members, the capacity `maxCnt` is not a concern in the `for` loop required.  Only the current size, `count`.

Comment: Do you even need to use `maxCnt` here? What does `maxCnt` represent? How is it different from `count`? To answer this, you also need to understand what `items` is. The comment says "The underlying array" but `items` is declared as a pointer, not an array. I have a guess about what this all means. I suggest you work on learning what pointers are and how they are related to arrays.

Comment: @rukhi98 I left an answer below. Can you let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Using parenthesis around a class declaration: `class AList( ... );` is illegal. Use curly braces instead: `class AList{ ... };`

Comment: @Casey thank you, I will keep that in mind - didn't know curly braces had to be used for class declaration instead, good to know!

Comment: @Perette thank you, I was a little confused with how maxCnt came into play but this makes a lot of sense as I'm only concerned with the current size (count)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you as well. Agreed, I think I'll start working on pointers to better understand how they work with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
void fill(const ItemType & it){
    for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
        items[i]=it;
    }
}
```

The for loop just iterates through each index in `items` and replaces its value with `it`.

Comment: @Perette I'm certain my method is valid. If you downvoted, please undo that unless you can prove otherwise. ```(*items)[i] = it;```  will not work nonetheless.

Comment: @Wes 1. You give a working answer to a clear homework problem. 2. Your answer assumes that the pointer was allocated correctly, which seems like a wild assumption given the OP's apparently level.

Comment: @Wes thank you for your help! This was helpful in explaining why the for loop is being used and I was able to understand the fill method better

Comment: @rukhi98 glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your class to provide `begin()` and `end()` iterators, you can use `std::transform`:

```
void fill(const ItemType &it) {
  std::transform(this->begin(), 
                 this->end(), 
                 this->begin(), 
                 [it](const ItemType &) { 
                   return it;
                 }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delegate to `std::fill`. The newer syntax of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` allows for the use of C-style arrays. If you change the implementation to a `std::vector` or `std::array` nothing else needs to change for it to work.

```cpp
template <typename ItemType>
class AList {
public:

    // Other functions omitted.

    void fill(const ItemType &it) {
        std::fill(std::begin(items), std::end(items), it);
    }

protected:
private: 
    ItemType* items{nullptr};
    std::size_t count{};
    std::size_t maxCnt{};

};
```